Как сделать swiper autoplay с несколькими видео?
Я пытаюсь сделать swiper автоплей с несколькими видео. подскажите как останавливать виде если слайд не активен и запускать как только он активен? Я вроде разобрался, но при loop swiper делает дубликаты и на дубликаты он не вешает класс, по которому я останавливаю видео. Так же нужно что-бы слайд переключался только после того как закончится видео, а не по времени, которое устанавливается в swiper, тут я вообще не понимаю как сделать. Есть ли вообще такая функция? Спасибо!
<div class="main-home__slider swiper">
                <div class="main-home__wrapper swiper-wrapper">
                    <div class="main-home__slide swiper-slide">
                        <video muted loop playsinline loading="lazy" class="vv" src="./files/videos/video.mp4">
                            <source loading="lazy" src="./files/videos/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                        </video>
                    </div>
                    <div class="main-home__slide swiper-slide">
                        <video muted loop playsinline loading="lazy" class="vv is-flipped"
                            src="./files/videos/video-2.mp4">
                            <source loading="lazy" src="./files/videos/video-2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                        </video>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

function vidik() {
    const videos = document.querySelectorAll('.video');
    videos.forEach(video => {
        const videoSlider = video.classList.contains('.is-flipped');
        if (videoSlider) {
            video.pause();
        } else {
            video.play();
        }
    });

}

mainSlider.on('slideChange', function () {
    //let activeIndex = mainSlider.contains.;
    const swiperSlides = document.querySelectorAll('.video');
    let video = document.querySelector(".swiper-slide-active .video");
    video.currentTime = 0;
    //console.log(video)
    swiperSlides.forEach(function (item, index) {
        console.log(activeIndex)
        if (activeIndex == index) {
            item.classList.add('is-flipped');
            vidik();
        } else {
            item.classList.remove('is-flipped');
            vidik();
        }
    });
});

